# Java script validation symbol % must not allow in text field

Tags: javascript

I am working in javascript. I want to add validation on my text field that only characters are allowed.

along with characters, I allowed left arrow key which has keycode 37. But this is creating problem because keycode of % is also 37. And I dont want to allow % symbol.

Please suggest me how can I differenciate % and left arrow key , because both key code are 37 ?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to sanitize input for SQL generation purposes. I am not suggesting you don't know about it, but just a friendly reminder - apply the same logic **on the server side** as well.

Comment: What do you mean "only characters"? "%" is a character. Do you mean "only alphanumeric characters" or something?

Comment: yes i mean to say alpha numeric character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press the 'percent' key the char code is 37, for the 'left arrow'-key it's not 37; e.g.:

```
$('#test').keypress(function(oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.charCode == 37) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waEsk/1/).

=== UPDATE ===

For additional internet explorer support:

```
$('#test').keypress(function(oEvent) {
    var iCode = typeof oEvent.charCode == 'number' ? oEvent.charCode : oEvent.keyCode;
    if (iCode == 37) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waEsk/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Don't limit the keypresses for validation. People can just copy/paste to overcome that.

You need to use Regex so validate your input.

Learn more about it from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: The alternative to keypress validation isn't regex, it's onchange, onblur and/or onsubmit. (Of course you can use regex in your change/submit validation, but you don't have to.)

Answer (score 0):

You should validate your user input after the user submits the form. You can write a function that the form's "onsubmit" attribute runs before the data is submitted to the server, or you can set the form action to "action='javascript:someFunction()'" either way will work. Disallowing keystrokes makes the user interface more complicated and cumbersome for the end user and poses security risks for xss or injection attacks. I would advise checking user input with javascript and returning an error message if it is invalid, then on the server side validating the data once more, and sanitizing the data.

Comment: I agree that preventing keystrokes tends to make the UI more cumbersome, but why do you think it poses security risks?

Comment: if that is the only way that the data is validated, there are several ways around the javascript to submit invalid data.

Comment: You always have to validate on the server, regardless of how you do (or don't) validate on the client, but what has that to do with preventing keystrokes as compared to validating `onsubmit`?